# Help with creating a scheduled task

Tags: vb.net, time

I came across this code which should be able to compare my PC time with the time stored in theTime; however, I can't get it to work. Can anybody help?

```
dim theTime as datetime

theTime = CDate(txtTime.Text)

if theTime.hour = now.hour and theTime.minute = now.minute then
'shut down code
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Shutdown.exe", "-s -t 0")
end if
```

Comment: "however i cant get it to work" - can you be more explicit?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `now` with `DateTime.now` -

```
dim theTime as datetime

theTime = CDate(txtTime.Text)

if theTime.hour = DateTime.now.hour and theTime.minute = DateTime.now.minute then
'shut down code
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Shutdown.exe", "-s -t 0")
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim theTime as DateTime
theTime = CDate(txtTime.Text)
If theTime.hour = DateTime.now.hour and theTime.minute = DateTime.now.minute then
Shell("Shutdown /s") 'to shutdown
End if
```

You can try the following also

```
Shell("Shutdwon /r") 'to restart
Shell("Shutdown /l") 'to logoff
Shell("Shutdown /a") 'to Abort
```